# Purpose of avalanching

Tags: hash, computer-science

I was researching different hash functions and came across [SuperFastHash](http://landman-code.blogspot.se/2009/02/c-superfasthash-and-murmurhash2.html). This hashing function used a technique called "avalanching" which was defined like this:

```
/* Force "avalanching" of final 127 bits */
hash ^= hash << 3;
hash += hash >> 5;
hash ^= hash << 4;
hash += hash >> 17;
hash ^= hash << 25;
hash += hash >> 6;
```

What is the purpose of avalanching? Why are theese specific bit shift steps used (3, 5, 4..)?

Comment: [Small change in input --> big change in hash.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalanching is just a term to define the "difussion" of small changes on input to the final result, for criptographic hashes where non-reversability is a really crucial having similar inputs provide really different results is a desirable feature to avoid an approximation attack crack a single hash.
See more info about this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect

I can not see why it uses that steps but it is using AND and XOR with the own shifted result to increase the diffusion, probably other values will perform similar but that will need a deeper analysis

Comment: So the purpose of avalanching is just to reduce the number of collisions?

Comment: @alex No, nonavalanched hashes should do equally fine at collisions. (That said this is intuition, not something I can prove.) It should however reduce clustering for "real-world" input. (Like using a hash table to store a sparse array.)

Comment: @alexn Not collission, just that two similar inputs gives very different results, other wise you cound start hashing random values and doing slightly changes to the input find easily a collission, just comparing the result of the changes on the output